# How do I display the results for the specifically chosen teams?

Tags: python

I am making a program to check the results of today NHL games. I check the scores of each game and compare them and print who is winning and by how much. Can someone tell me how I go about having my checker only display if the team I chose is winning or losing.

```
(Carolina Hurricanes: Winning 
 Toronto Maple Leafs: Winning
 Carolina Hurricanes: Losing )
```

Currently my code checks every game for the day not just the ones I am looking for.

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

ids = []
iswinning = []
try:
    response = requests.get(
        'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?expand=schedule.teams,schedule.linescore')
    response.raise_for_status()
    jsonResponse = response.json()
    games = jsonResponse["dates"][0]['games']
    for i in games:
        ids.append(i['gamePk'])


except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')


def game_compare(n):
    url = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/" + str(n) + "/feed/live"
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        jsonResponse = response.json()
        home = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['home']['team']['name']
        goals_home = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['home']['goals']
        away = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['away']['team']['name']
        goals_away = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['away']['goals']
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
    if goals_home > goals_away:
        print(home + " is winning by " + str((goals_home - goals_away)))
    elif goals_home < goals_away:
        print(away + " is winning by " + str((goals_away - goals_home)))
    else:
        print(home + " is tied with " + away)

for i in ids:
    game_compare(i)
```

Comment: Create a list of favorite teams `favorites = ["Carolina Hurricanes", "Toronto Maple Leafs"]` Then, before you print stuff: `if home in favorites or away in favorites: ....`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list (that way you can have more than 1 team if needed) of the teams you want. Then in your function to compare, check to see if the home team or the away team is in your list. If they are not, return `None` as you don't need it to compare the scores. Since there's also a status on the game (Ie if it's live or final), you could also make it more dynamic in saying a team won as opposed to saying is winning:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError


teamChosen = ['Chicago Blackhawks']


ids = []
iswinning = []
try:
    response = requests.get(
        'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?expand=schedule.teams,schedule.linescore')
    response.raise_for_status()
    jsonResponse = response.json()
    games = jsonResponse["dates"][0]['games']
    for i in games:
        ids.append(i['gamePk'])


except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')


def game_compare(n):
    status_resp = {'win':{'Live':'is winning','Final':'won'},
                   'tie':{'Live':'is tied','Final':'tied'}}
    url = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/" + str(n) + "/feed/live"
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        jsonResponse = response.json()
        home = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['home']['team']['name']
        goals_home = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['home']['goals']
        away = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['away']['team']['name']
        goals_away = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['away']['goals']
        
        status = jsonResponse['gameData']['status']['detailedState']
        if status != 'Final':
            status = 'Live'
            
        
        if home not in teamChosen and away not in teamChosen:
            return None
        
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
    if goals_home > goals_away:
        print(home + " %s by " %(status_resp['win'][status]) + str((goals_home - goals_away)))
    elif goals_home < goals_away:
        print(away + " %s by " %(status_resp['win'][status]) + str((goals_away - goals_home)))
    else:
        print(home + " %s with " %(status_resp['tie'][status]) + away)

for i in ids:
    game_compare(i)
```

**Output:**

```
Chicago Blackhawks won by 1
```